# Easy, painless way to test new mercurial hooks (that are works in progress)

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm in the process of writing a mercurial changegroup hook. I don't have everything figured out yet, but the process of trial and error is made more painful by the fact that I have to keep committing and pushing just to test my work in progress.

Is there any way to 'fake' a trigger to execute my changegroup hook with the current status of the repository to be used for it's parameters?

Any help to streamline this process would be very much appreciated.
Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no built-in debugging capabilities for this. What I do when writing a hook is to setup two local repositories:

```
$ hg init repo
$ hg clone repo clone
```

and then configure the `changegroup` hook in `repo`. Now go into `clone` and do

```
$ echo a > a
$ hg add a
$ hg commit -m 'a file'
```

to setup `clone`. Every time I want to check the hook, I run

```
$ hg push; hg  -R ../repo rollback
```

inside `clone`. I keep that in my command line history so that I can just press <kbd>↑</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> to execute it again and again. The `hg rollback` is the key: is effectively cancels the `hg push` so that I can repeat it again and again.

You will of course need to adjust this as needed for your hook. If the hook checks the committer name, then use `hg commit -u someone` to set this as needed. If the hook needs more than one changeset in the changegroup, then make two or more commits before pushing — rollback will take care of removing all the pushed changesets. If the hook is run by `hgweb`, then run

```
$ hg serve --config 'web.push_ssl=no' --config 'web.allow_push=*'
```

in one terminal to serve `repo` while you push to it in another terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that's simplifying the way I was going about it in several ways! :)

Answer (score 6):

I've recently been writing a python hook for Mercurial using the API. To test it, I did the following, after launching the python interpreter inside the repository folder.

```
from mercurial import ui, hg
repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), '.')
execfile('./myhook.py')
myhook(repo.ui, repo, 'hash', 'outgoing')
```

Where `myhook` is your hook function (located in `myhook.py`), `hash` is the hash of the changeset you want to test your hook with, and `outgoing` is the hook type.

If your hook doesn't behave as expected you can modify your script and execute the last two lines again to retry.